# steps for upgrading sharepoint 2013 to service pack1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade

I want to upgrade my SHAREPOINT 2013 RTM version to SERVICE PACK1. Also, i have to upgrade my sql server 2012 to  SP2 version. so i have completed the sql server  upgrade from 2012 to 2012 service pack2. 
MY current Version Number of SP 2013 is 15.0.4420.1017

Now, how can i upgrade SHAREPOINT 2013 TO SERVICE PACK1 ?
should i upgrade by directly running the sharepoint 2013 SP1 ISO FILE?

or

should i just run the SP1 EXE thats freely available from msft download center?
i have attached my current SP 2013 version number:
 [image: SP2013-VERSION-NUM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 foundation download from this link

[Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB2880551)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42548)

If you are using SharePoint 2013 Server download from this link

[Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42544)

The installation package is 1.3 GB for Server and 403 MB for Foundation. Ensure you have the necessary disk space available before downloading.

Run the exe and then run the SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard.

Once done, you need to verify the build number to be absolutely certain that the installation was successfull.

To do that, Open Central Admin > Manage servers in the farm.

The Configuration database version should read `15.0.4571.1502`

Reference - [Install SP 2013 SP1](http://blog.fpweb.net/how-to-install-sharepoint-2013-service-pack-1/)

Comment: Will this upgrade,badly affect / -vely impact my existing Sp 2013 rtm env? When I simply try to run the Sp 2013 sp1 iso file, it asked me to repair/ remove. I selected repair , but it didn't result in success.. I successfully upgraded the SQL 2012 to SP2 . n ran the config wizard. Mine is 2 server farm, 1 wife server & 1 SQL on another box.

Comment: i dont think it will affect your farm negatively. Just run the SP1 exe on your RTM env on SP server and then run config wizard. It should take care of the upgrade. After running the wizard, i dont think it will require restart , but i would suggest that you restart the servers

Comment: @SaMolPP - you just need to install the SP1 exe available freely on the links provided. No need to run ISO file.

Answer (score 3):

As you know Service Pack 1 is a mandatory requirement for installing any subsequent SharePoint 2013 cumulative updates as the new baseline!

In your case, you just need to install the Service Pack 1 over SharePoint 2013 RTM from [Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=42544)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the SharePoint environment required some planning as it will have impact on the environment. As per my experience I would do it following way

- apply SP 1 in lower farm and do the testing and make sure the all functionality you are using working after the upgrade.once satisfied
- plan a date and time as it will cause outage for end user
- before start take a full backup of sharepoint farm, once sp1 installed you can't uninstall it, so in case of disaster you can recover it without losing data
- now download the **SharePoint Sp1 from MSFT site the exe file** you don't need to run ISO file as it is complete sharepoint package but you just need the sp1
- install SP1 on all sharepoint servers.once completed.then
- Run sharepoint config wizard on all servers in the farm.it should be one server at a time. I would start from central admin server.once done
- now test your farm, functionality, build number etc

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

One thing wasn't mentioned in previous answers: If you have installed a SharePoint LanguagePack, you also have to install the [LanguagePack SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42543). Install it directly after SharePoint SP1 binaries for each language and then execute ProductsConfiguration Wizard.

If You already installed SP1 without LP-SP1, you can install it afterwards. Please remember to also run ProductsConfig Wizard.

PS: If you forget to install LP-SP1, you won't be able to install any following CumulativeUpdates. You will get a very generic error during Update-Detection ("Update not applicaple to your system"), so this situation is hard to identify.